# rs.next() returning false when there are record exists

Tags: java, prepared-statement, resultset

In while loop it did not go inside. But record exists in the database. Why result set returns false in this case?

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename where name=?";
PreparedStatement smt = con.preparestatement(sql);
smt.setString(1, "john");
ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
List<Object> colValues = new ArrayList<Object>();

while(rs.next()) {
   for(int i=1;i<=columnCount;i++) {
       name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
       Object name1 = rs.getObject(name);
       colValues.add(name1);
   }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have some doubts or confusion about SQL works.  It is not correct usage to search for a column name in a SQL query.  Rather, you should be asserting that a particular already known column has a certain string value.  Also, you refer to a result set called `rs1` in your Java code, yet this is not defined anywhere.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry Typo mistake. This is the correct snippet. Can you guide me here?

Comment: If your code really never enters the `while` loop, then there are no records with a name of John.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But it exists in the database.

Comment: Not according to the query you are using above.

Comment: why use `for loop` in inside `while loop`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen By using the above code,I get the columnname of the entry

Comment: Be aware that SQL string comparison is case sensitive, so `"John"` isn't the same as `"john"`.

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej I do not know the exact column names. So I loop through till the column count. Then by using the metadata ,i get the column name

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem yeah it is john only

Comment: change `colNames.add(name1);` to `colValues.add(name1);`

Comment: Try to make an SQL statement in your SQL client that correctly returns the row you're looking for.  Then compare it to the SQL in your Java code.  Another avenue to go down would be to step through with your debugger, to make sure that you really are skipping out the `while` loop.

Comment: Put `Stacktrace` in your question

Comment: What DBMS are you using? (Oracle or MySQL or SQL Server or PostgreSQL) What is the data type of column `name` in database table `tablename`? (Is it `char` or `varchar`?) Note that you can use `Object name1 = rs.getObject(i)` to get the column value.

Comment: I used Object name1 = rs.getObject(i) this also. But It didn't work. Actually it didn't go inside the while loop @Abra

Comment: My comment was not meant to be a solution. It was a general comment regarding how to extract data from a `ResultSet`. I may be able to give you a solution if you answer the other questions that I asked. Namely, what DBMS are you using and what is the data type of column `name` in database table `tablename`.